# fatal error: avr/interrupt.h rtcLib.h platform.io Esp32 Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp32, platformio

I am developing with VisualStudio Code and Platform.IO installed.

I am using ESP32 / TTGO T-CALL with Arduino Framework and added the RTCLib.h Adafruit v 1.11.0
Unfortunately the software is not compiling because I got the following error:

```
    Building in release mode
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\src\main.cpp.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\libfa0\TinyWireM\USI_TWI_Master.cpp.o
C:\Users\aleil\.platformio\lib\TinyWireM\USI_TWI_Master.cpp:28:27: fatal error: avr/interrupt.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Archiving .pio\build\esp32dev\lib46d\libRTClib.a
*** [.pio\build\esp32dev\libfa0\TinyWireM\USI_TWI_Master.cpp.o] Error 1
============================================ [FAILED] Took 8.69 seconds ============================================
The terminal process "C:\Users\aleil\.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe 'run'" terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Here there is the INCLUDING code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <StreamDebugger.h>
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <OneWire.h>                // x ds18b20 temperature sensors
#include <DallasTemperature.h>      // x ds18b20 temperature sensors
#include <esp_task_wdt.h>
#include "SPI.h" // Used to define SPI on SPI1
#include "SD.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <RTClib.h>
```

So I try to find a solution but I cannot find one. Does someone have some hint or solutions?

Comment: It looks like this libfa0/TinyWireM library is using headers specific to the AVR architecture. You will need to adapt it to ESP32. In the best case that is a simple preprocessor definition, in the worst case you will need to edit the library.

Comment: What is your `platformio.ini` setting? TinyWire is the dependency of RTClib, but it should only be included when the MCU is ATtiny, you can see from [RTClib.cpp](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib/blob/master/RTClib.cpp#L45-L50) that `Wire.h` will be use if the MCU is not `__AVR_ATtiny85__`.

Comment: Thanks, I added this in platformio.ini "lib_ignore = TinyWireM" and it work well

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but uninstalling the TinyWireM library (PlatformIO > Libraries > Installed) solved the problem.

I think the TinyWireM library is installed automatically with the RTClib library.